# MySQL update with linked tables updates join column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table tbl_sc_3_4_ps with following structure (multible entries for id_team are possible for one c_minute!!!):

```
+--------+---------+--------+----------+------+---------------------+
| id     | id_team | bill_n | bill_min | ps   | c_minute            |
+--------+---------+--------+----------+------+---------------------+
| 175019 | team1   | 0.0489 |     NULL | NULL | 2018-08-07 00:00:00 |
| 175020 | team1   | 0.0500 |     NULL | NULL | 2018-08-07 00:01:00 |
| 175021 | team1   | 0.0464 |     NULL | NULL | 2018-08-07 00:02:00 |
| 175022 | team1   | 0.0392 |     NULL | NULL | 2018-08-07 00:03:00 |
| 175023 | team1   | 0.0504 |     NULL | NULL | 2018-08-07 00:04:00 |
| 175024 | team1   | 0.0484 |     NULL | NULL | 2018-08-07 00:05:00 |
| 175025 | team1   | 0.0475 |     NULL | NULL | 2018-08-07 00:06:00 |
| 175026 | team1   | 0.0500 |     NULL | NULL | 2018-08-07 00:07:00 |
| 175027 | team1   | 0.0453 |     NULL | NULL | 2018-08-07 00:08:00 |
| 175028 | team1   | 0.0445 |     NULL | NULL | 2018-08-07 00:09:00 |
+--------+---------+--------+----------+------+---------------------+
```

and want to Update column bill_min from tbl_sc_3_4_bill_min (only one bill_min is possible for one c_minute, c_minute is the pkey):

```
+---------------------+----------+
| c_minute            | bill_min |
+---------------------+----------+
| 2018-08-07 00:00:00 |   0.0418 |
| 2018-08-07 00:01:00 |   0.0766 |
| 2018-08-07 00:02:00 |   0.1188 |
| 2018-08-07 00:03:00 |   0.1556 |
| 2018-08-07 00:04:00 |   0.2002 |
| 2018-08-07 00:05:00 |   0.2416 |
| 2018-08-07 00:06:00 |   0.2779 |
| 2018-08-07 00:07:00 |   0.3187 |
| 2018-08-07 00:08:00 |   0.3614 |
| 2018-08-07 00:09:00 |   0.4000 |
+---------------------+----------+
```

My SQL-Statement:

```
update dbsdme.tbl_su_3_4_ps as a
inner join dbsdme.tbl_sc_3_4_bill_min as b on b.c_minute = a.c_minute
set a.bill_min = b.bill_min
where a.bill_min is NULL;
```

This updates not only the bill_min column but also the c_minute column (with the timestamp when the query is perfomed):

```
+--------+---------+--------+----------+------+---------------------+
| id     | id_team | bill_n | bill_min | ps   | c_minute            |
+--------+---------+--------+----------+------+---------------------+
| 175019 | team1   | 0.0489 |   0.0418 | NULL | 2018-08-12 10:29:31 |
| 175020 | team1   | 0.0500 |   0.0766 | NULL | 2018-08-12 10:29:31 |
| 175021 | team1   | 0.0464 |   0.1188 | NULL | 2018-08-12 10:29:31 |
| 175022 | team1   | 0.0392 |   0.1556 | NULL | 2018-08-12 10:29:31 |
| 175023 | team1   | 0.0504 |   0.2002 | NULL | 2018-08-12 10:29:31 |
| 175024 | team1   | 0.0484 |   0.2416 | NULL | 2018-08-12 10:29:31 |
| 175025 | team1   | 0.0475 |   0.2779 | NULL | 2018-08-12 10:29:31 |
| 175026 | team1   | 0.0500 |   0.3187 | NULL | 2018-08-12 10:29:31 |
| 175027 | team1   | 0.0453 |   0.3614 | NULL | 2018-08-12 10:29:31 |
| 175028 | team1   | 0.0445 |   0.4000 | NULL | 2018-08-12 10:29:31 |
+--------+---------+--------+----------+------+---------------------+
```

Does somebody have any idea why the c_minute column is also updated? I Just want to update bill_min.

Best regards

Jan

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - also including any triggers

Comment: the update query you have in your question  .. can't updated  the c_minute columns  .. so you should check if you have some trigger related  to the table tbl_su_3_4_ps  involved in update ..

Comment: Is `c_minute` defined as `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Yes, it was the "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" property. Until now I didn't know about this property. Many thanks for your answers!!!!